# Open links in external browser webview

Tags: android, browser, webview, hyperlink

I'm new to this, so i'm in need of some help
I'm Trying to create an app from a website, using webview, but I want all the links that are not the website links, to open externally, on the browser, how do I do that?
here is my code, its not working as I intended, the website opens directly on browser instead of on webview

```
package com.app.catalogomacae;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
WebView webView;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
        //webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
        {
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)

            {
                String url2="https://catalogomacae.com.br/";
                // all links  with in ur site will be open inside the webview
                //links that start ur domain example(http://www.example.com/)
                if (url != null && url.startsWith(url2)){
                    return false;
                }
                // all links that points outside the site will be open in a normal android browser
                else
                {
                    view.getContext().startActivity(
                            new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
                    return true;
                }
            }
        });
        //webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.loadUrl("https://catalogomacae.com.br/appcatalogo");
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);


    }

        @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(webView.isFocused() && webView.canGoBack())
        {
            webView.goBack();
        }else{
            super.onBackPressed();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try debugging your `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` conditions ?

Comment: I haven't, let me try

Answer (score 0):

```
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
        view.loadUrl(request.getUrl().toString());
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: could you please be a little more specific and tell me how to use that piece of code you posted on my code? please